# root node positioning and horizontal alignment of child nodes

Tags: forest

I am trying to fit my tree on one A4 page.
Unfortunately i can't get it to align the nodes, as i want.

It currently looks like this:
[image: Current output]

As my tree is very one sided, I would like, that it looks more like this - root node on the left, child nodes fitted to each line with unequal edge angles, such that all nodes fit on one side.
[image]

The latex code to get the current plot, looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
     \forestset{
          EL/.style={% abbreviation for Edge Label
              edge label={node[midway, font=\small, text=black,
              fill=white, inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}}
              }
      }

      \begin{forest}
      for tree = {
          % node style
          %circle,
          draw=none,
          minimum size = 1.5em,
          inner sep=0pt,
          math content,
          % tree style
          edge={very thick},
          s sep=1mm,
          l sep=12mm,
      }
      [plus,
          [minus, edge=blue, EL=3000000, fit=band
              [xor, edge=blue, EL=2000000
                  [distr, edge=blue, EL=2000000, fit=band
                      [something, edge=black, EL=1234567]
                      [else, edge=black, EL=1000104]
                      [example, edge=blue, EL=500001]
                      [word, edge=black, EL=1700]
                      [node, edge=black, EL=904]
                      [mul, edge=black, EL=901]
                      [division, edge=black, EL=78]
                      [plus, edge=black, EL=31]
                      [minus plus mul, edge=black, EL=3]
                  ]
              ]
              [something, edge=black, EL=1000
                  [, edge=black, EL=\dots]
              ]
              [hello, edge=black, EL=400
                  [, edge=black, EL=\dots]
              ]
              [for each, edge=black, EL=300
                  [, edge=black, EL=\dots]
              ]
              [for, edge=black, EL=20
                  [, edge=black, EL=\dots]
              ]
              [if, edge=black, EL=15
                  [, edge=black, EL=\dots]
              ]
          ]
          [else, edge=black, EL=4, fit=band
              [, edge=black, EL=\dots]
          ]
      ]
     \end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: `for tree={calign=first}` would be a good start, I think. Section 2.2 of [the manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/forest/0) has an example for this, that's very close to your diagram.

Comment: `where n=1{calign with current edge}{}`?

Comment: Remove `fit=band`. It tells `forest` NOT to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's straightforward to align the first child with the parent. `where n=1{calign with current edge}` will align the parent and child anchors, basically, so the edges line up vertically on the left.

[image: aligned, but not very intelligible]

But the result is not very intelligible. If your actual tree is similar, I think you need to rethink what it is going to look like. I don't know sufficient to know what might work, but rotating some of the nodes and replacing `\dots` in edge nodes with dotted edges may help.

`fit=band` tells `forest` not to use any of the space vertically beneath this subtree. That's what's forcing thing far to the right. So you need to remove those.

[image: remove fit=band]

Your code seems rather at odds with the target appearance, so I'm not sure what you intend exactly. Aside from `fit=band`, your target uses sans-serif fonts, whereas your code isn't using text fonts at all. If you want text fonts, remove `math content`. If you want sans, add `font=\sffamily` to the `for tree` list.

Here's a possible sketch of an approach. This easily fits on A4 and is reasonably compact and clear.

[image: possible approach to fitting sprawling tree onto A4]

Note that the edge nodes are still in serif, because they're explicitly put into maths mode. Since they're numbers, I left those.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\forestset{%
  declare toks={EL}{},
  declare boolean={turned}{0},
  EL style/.style={% abbreviation for Edge Label
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where EL={}{%
        if content={}{%
          edge+=dotted,
        }{%
        },
      }{%
        if n=1{%
          EL left/.option=EL,
        }{%
          if turned={%
            EL perp/.option=EL,edge path'={(!u.parent anchor) -| (.child anchor)},
          }{%
            EL standard/.option=EL,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  EL standard/.style={edge label={node[midway,font=\small,text=black,fill=white,inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}}},
  EL left/.style={edge label={node[midway,left,font=\small,anchor=east,inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}}},
  EL perp/.style={edge label={node[pos=.75,rotate=-90,font=\small,above,inner sep=2pt]{$#1$}}},
}

\begin{forest}
  for tree = {%
    % node style
    font=\sffamily,
    % tree style
    edge={very thick,black},
    s sep'=1mm,
    l sep'=12mm,
  },
  EL style,
  where n=1{
    calign with current edge,
  }{},
  where={ > On= On= | {n}{1} {n}{0} }{
    for children={if n=1{}{turned,}},
  }{},
  where={> On= On=! & {n children}{0}{n}{1} }{turned,rotate=-90, anchor=base west, child anchor=base west,}{},
  [plus,
    [minus, edge=blue, EL=3000000
        [xor, edge=blue, EL=2000000
            [distr, edge=blue, EL=2000000
                [something,  EL=1234567]
                [else,  EL=1000104]
                [example, edge=blue, EL=500001]
                [word,  EL=1700]
                [node,  EL=904]
                [mul,  EL=901]
                [division,  EL=78]
                [plus,  EL=31]
                [minus plus mul,  EL=3]
            ]
        ]
        [something,  EL=1000
            []
        ]
        [hello,  EL=400
            []
        ]
        [for each,  EL=300
            []
        ]
        [for,  EL=20
            []
        ]
        [if,  EL=15
            []
        ]
    ]
    [else,  EL=4
        []
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - i adapted your solution and configured it a bit, such that it matches my expectations.